# How to style a column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to make a conditional formatting, which is applied on another column in a pandas dataframe.

| ID | v | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | XYz |
| 2 | 4 | ABC |
| 3 | -5 | FFF |
| 4 | 6 | 34S |

So I want to change the font-color to red in column "key", if value in column "v" is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a highlighter function and color values conditionally.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def red_or_auto(x):
    # set font color to red for keys whose corresponding v is positive
    # all other values have default font color
    return pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns).assign(key=np.where(x['v']>0, "color:red", ''))

# apply the highlighter function red_or_auto to 'v' and'key' columns of df
df_styled = df.style.apply(red_or_auto, axis=None, subset=['v', 'key'])
df_styled
```

[image]